# Are backticks used outside of computing?

Tags: punctuation

Is the backtick character ("`") used outside of computing in English? If so, what for?

Comment: Some will regard `\`` as the proper way to open a quote to be closed with `'`.

Comment: Also, if you're typesetting your document using LaTeX (used in mathematics and other fields of science, but not limited to the sciences), then to get the correct quotation marks for opening a quote you definitely need either `\`` or `\`\`` to be closed with either `'` or `''` respectively.  `"` is not used for quotation marks in LaTeX.  For examples you might want to start by looking at [this entry on quotation marks from the TeX.SE site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50712/22413)

Comment: The answer is 'no'. I've never seen a backtick in any work of English literature.

Comment: @A.Ellett But only in ASCII. An actual single open quote is a different glyph.

Comment: beautiful question.

Comment: Understand that the common US computer keyboard is derived from the old Teletype ASR-33 keyboard, the most common input-output device for early computers, and the "mother" of the ASCII character set.  There were only 94 total character values available, so the last 6 or so were allocated rather arbitrarily (by engineers, not linguists).  The "backquote" was picked partially to permit poor-man's "accents", and partially to pair with the "forward" single quote character.  What key combinations modern "word processors" use to evoke "extended characters" is up to those programs.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "outside of computing": Wikipedia mentions it's used in word processing and text editing to enter accented characters or for quotation marks; does that count as computing? It was formerly used on typewriters for many of the same purposes. The usual transliteration of the Arabic letter ʿayn is very similar, and a backtick can be used for that, although a better system will use a distinct character; whether that counts as computing is again up to you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not.

The backtick, or the backquote, evolved as a separate character exclusively for computer use. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming))

It is actually a grave accent, used in combination with a letter in many languages, but not English, except sometimes to indicate pronunciation.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#English):

> The grave accent, although not commonly applied to any English words, is sometimes used in poetry and song lyrics to indicate that a vowel usually silent is to be pronounced, in order to fit the rhythm or meter
>
> ...It can also be used in this capacity to distinguish certain pairs of identically spelled words like the past tense of learn, learned /ˈlɜrnd/, from the adjective learnèd /ˈlɜrn.ɨd/ (for example, "a very learnèd man").

**EDIT:** As Steven noted in the comments, loanwords which use grave accents often retain them in English.

> Accents, sometimes combined with italics, are often applied to foreign terms that are uncommonly used in or have not been fully assimilated into English: for example, vis-à-vis, résumé, pièce de résistance and crème brûlée.

Comment: Haven't you ever eaten pie à la mode?  Or chicken à la king?

Comment: @StevenLittman: Okay, loanwords do retain them, I guess. And I'm craving ice-cream now!

Comment: @Joe: Get real. It's been ten years since *Nature* reported that Wikipedia was as reliable as Encyclopaedia Britannica, and [it's almost certainly better than that today](http://blog.wikimedia.org/2012/08/02/seven-years-after-nature-pilot-study-compares-wikipedia-favorably-to-other-encyclopedias-in-three-languages/) (it'll certainly cover far more ground, in more different languages).

Comment: The ` character is only a grave accent when it is attached to a letter: it is the letter that provides the context in which an accent is used. Otherwise the backtick/backquote is a separate character, regardless of the fact that it looks identical to a grave accent.

Comment: The backslash has a similar history, invented for computing and now the bane of customer support everywhere. I hate having to say *forward slash* much like I hate having to say *email inbox*; it reminds me of my age.

Comment: @choster: Heard the one about 'Press ANY key'? Reminds me of that. I really think it should be common knowledge that slash means forward slash. Just like 1 means +1.